# man: can't open /usr/share/man/man3/std::basic_iostream.3cxx: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, linux, debian, libstdc++, manpage

I have installed `ligstdc++-4.9-dev` and `libstdc++-4.9-doc`, and I want to scan the information of the library of c++ through `man` like the style in C. 
But when I run "man std::iostream", I encount an error shows that `man: can't open /usr/share/man/man3/std::basic_iostream.3cxx: No such file or directory`. 
I've checked the `/usr/share/man/man3/` directory and find the file named `std::iostream.3cxx.gz`, but why I cound not get the manpages of the `std::iostream`?
The output of `uname -a` is `Linux hostname 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.7-ckt9-3~deb8u1 (2015-04-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

Hope for help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The man page std::iostream.3.gz has this at the top:

```
.so man3/std::basic_iostream.3
```

which says that when someone types man std::iostream, instead source the page std::basic_iostream. Unfortunately whoever built the package for your system built it wrong and left that out, or alternatively, gcc's build tree doesn't build it right. I don't know which.  Sorry.

Comment: Well, you mean that there's something wrong with gcc's build tree?

Answer (score 0):

I tried in libstdc++-5-doc and libstdc++6-4.7-doc on Ubuntu 16.04.

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-5-doc
```

or

```
sudo apt install libstdc++6-4.7-doc
```

In libstdc++-5-doc, I successed `man std::ostream`, but in libstdc++6-4.7-doc, failured as same as your error message.

So why don't you change the version of libstdc++?